# Arraylist multiple dimensions C# 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, c#-2.0

I am trying to create a multi dimension array

What I have so far is...

```
ArrayList iEFiles = (ArrayList)Session["Files"];
iEFiles.Add(Server.MapPath(FileName));

FileName = "Testing123"
FileName = "AnotherTest"
```

What I want it to do is have it come out like this...

```
FileName = ("Testing123", "Waterproof")
FileName = ("AnotherTest", "Non-Waterproof")
```

Like `Array[,]`

Any ideas?

To display the records... 
 BindGridview(iEFiles);

```
    private void BindGridview(ArrayList list)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("FileName");
        dt.Columns.Add("id");
        dt.Columns.Add("snFile");
        int c = list.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[i]["FileName"] = list[i].ToString().ToUpper();
            dt.Rows[i]["id"] = i;
            dt.Rows[i]["snFile"] = list[i].ToString();
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: why are you still using `ArrayList`, use `List<T>` and have  a class which have two string properties.

Comment: Not sure on how to use that.  We have been using this at the office for a while.  C# 2.0

Comment: @user2800287 Then consider this a fantastic oppertunity to learn something new that will make your usage of lists much more effective, less error prone, and in some cases more performant.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Hashtable / Dictionary` to store the key value pair. If you do not want that you can make a class having two attributes `FileName` and `Value` and store object of that class in ArrayList or preferably generic `List<T>`.

```
class FileInformation
{
  public FileInformation(string fileName, string value)
  {
     FileName = fileName;
     Value = value;
  }
  public string FileName;
  public string Value;
}

List<FileInformation> lst = new List<FileInformation>();
lst.Add(new FileInformation("fileName", "somevalue"));
```

Comment: C# 2.0 is what we have.

Comment: @user2800287 Then you have both `List` and `Dictionary`, and shouldn't be using `ArrayList` at all, or `HashTable` for that matter.

Comment: You should really have read only properties rather than public fields in that `FileInformation` class.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList is a bit of a .net 1.x throwback before we had generics.

You could use `Dictionary<string,string>` to store these values but the first item is a key and has to be unique.  If you just want to store a list of 2 values you could use something like `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` or `List<string[]>`.